# Getting Rails to work on Heroku with Mongo db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

I have downloaded an open-source code [ribbot](https://github.com/barmstrong/ribbot.git). I am new to Ruby and Rails but I have set up my environment and was able to get this code to run on my local machine.

I wanted to use Heroku as my server base solution. I pushed this app to Heroku. Heroku seems to tell me that the app is running fine however I keep getting redirected to an error page via the open-source code; it doesn't do so on my local machine. I suspect that it has something to do with Mongo. I have downloaded the add on MongoHQ for Heroku and am still experiencing this problem. I do know that this code uses mongoid:

```
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost:11211 failed (count: 2)
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.124.140.154 at 2012-04-16 19:06:47 +0000
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: allow_dynamic_fields is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: autocreate_indexes is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: identity_map_enabled is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: include_root_in_json is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: include_type_for_serialization is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: max_retries_on_connection_failure is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: parameterize_keys is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: scope_overwrite_exception is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: persist_in_safe_mode is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: preload_models is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: raise_not_found_error is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: skip_version_check is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: time_zone is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: use_utc is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:47+00:00 app[web.1]: timestamped_migrations is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Mongo::ConnectionFailure (Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017):
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `current_forum'
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:40:in `require_current_forum!'
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2997ms
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_request.text.erb (0.2ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.0ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb (0.2ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.0ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_environment.text.erb (23.9ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.0ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_backtrace.text.erb (0.1ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.0ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb (26.8ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to barmstrong@gmail.com (274ms)
2012-04-16T19:06:50+00:00 heroku[router]: GET impact-project.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3832ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost:11211 failed (count: 3)
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss, store
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-16 19:06:51] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2012-04-16T19:06:51+00:00 heroku[router]: GET impact-project.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=517ms status=500 bytes=337
```

Comment: Can we see your `config/mongoid.yml`?

Comment: Also, have you installed any of the Mongo add-ons on Heroku?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. Yes I have added the mongo add-ons

Comment: development:
  host: localhost
  database: ribbot_development

test:
  host: localhost
  database: ribbot_test

production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>

Comment: Does this mean I should use mongolab instead of mongoHQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've installed the MongoHQ add-on in Heroku, it creates a MONGOHQ_URL environment variable which your Rails app can use to connect to the database. Looks like your config/mongoid.yml isn't configured properly. Here's a working example for Heroku & MongoHQ:

```
development:
    host: localhost
    database: yourapp_dev

test:
   host: localhost
   database: yourapp_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
    uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just saw that my mongoid.yml is very simillar to urs but mine specified MONGOLAB_IRL. Does this mean I should install the mongolab add on?

Comment: It just depends on what your Heroku app is using and what your preferences are. Check to see if you have either addon installed on your app by using the command ```heroku addons``` in your CLI. If neither are there, just pick and use whichever you like. The environment variable should work the same either way in your Rails config.